# How to exclude a specific file or directory from OneDrive within the OneDrive folder structure

Tags: windows, onedrive

There is no way using the UI to specify that OneDrive should not sync a specific file, filetype or folder inside the OneDrive folder structure.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Doesn't work anymore ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

<strike>Simply make the file both **hidden** and **system**, and OneDrive will not sync it. If it has already been synced, you'll also need to [delete it online](https://onedrive.live.com/) as well.</strike>

To make a file **hidden** and **system** open a command window and enter the following command:

```
attrib -A +S +H path\to\file\filename.ext
```

<strike>Note that after this change by default the file or folder will no longer be visible unless you change the relevant windows explorer setting.</strike>

Comment: it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late but there was an updated as I posted [here](https://superuser.com/a/1626632/947906).

OneDrive added this feature a short while ago. Well somewhat. If you are using the OneDrive insider preview you can do this:

Copy `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\{OneDriveVersion}\adm` `OneDrive.adml` (language file) to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-US` and the `OneDrive.admx` to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`.

Then in the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> All Settings and find `Exclude specific kinds of files from being uploaded`. Now there you can specify specific file types or file names to ignore.

See also https://senpai.club/exclude-file-types/ and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-onedrive-blog/celebrating-the-top-onedrive-moments-from-microsoft-ignite-2020/ba-p/1679821

Answer (score 0):

There is also a solution for MacOS to ignore file types. I have not yet tested if it works to ignore full folders.

The documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/deploy-and-configure-on-macos#enableodignore

If I understand it correctly, you have to edit `~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.OneDrive.plist`, ideally using a [PList-aware editor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/5288/256267). In this file, you should add a key `EnableODIgnore`, of type `array`, and inside the key, you add as `string` the file patterns to ignore, such as `*.txt~`.

If you have installed OneDrive from the App Store, the file to edit is `~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac/Data/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.OneDrive-mac.plist`

It works. So far tested on file extension `*.heic`. Here's the entry in the plist:

```
$ plutil -convert xml1 -o - com.microsoft.OneDrive.plist | grep -A 3 EnableODIgnore
    <key>EnableODIgnore</key>
    <array>
        <string>*.heic</string>
    </array>
```

And here's what Finder shows for this file:

[image: screenshot of Finder with icon of OneDrive which is hovered and displays "Excluded from sync"]

"Excluded from sync".

Next up, ignoring `node_modules`