# Exclude specific file types or large files from OneDrive syncing

Tags: windows, sync, onedrive

As described in the title I would like to exclude some files from syncing to my  (personal) OneDrive to save some space.
I have some folders that I wish to sync but in some of them there are quite large video files which I do not want to sync.

I found [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/block-file-types) from microsoft but I do not have the "Sync" option after I click on the "OneDrive admin center" link.

Also I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1329689/how-to-exclude-a-specific-file-or-directory-from-onedrive-within-the-onedrive-fo) but the answer no longer works.

Comment: Is it your personal OneDrive account, or do you use a work /school account?

Comment: I have a personal OneDrive account

Comment: Sorry it's not possible I was looking to do this yesterday! https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/stopping-onedrive-from-syncing-specific-files/e5f3fd2e-6ec4-403b-9435-1ada19026919

Comment: Thanks @RobSedgwick I guess I will get Google Drive then.

Comment: Unfortunately, the personal OneDrive does not have such powerful feature. The document "[Block syncing of specific file types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/block-file-types)" is for OneDrive for Business.

Answer (score 6):

OneDrive added this feature a short while ago. Well somewhat. If you are using the OneDrive insider preview you can do this:

Copy `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\OneDrive\{OneDriveVersion}\adm` `OneDrive.adml` (language file) to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\en-US` and the `OneDrive.admx` to `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions`.

Then in the Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> All Settings and find `Exclude specific kinds of files from being uploaded`. Now there you can specify specific file types or file names to ignore.

See also https://senpai.club/exclude-file-types/ and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-onedrive-blog/celebrating-the-top-onedrive-moments-from-microsoft-ignite-2020/ba-p/1679821

Answer (score 5):

Go to this folder

```
\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\settings\Business1
```

Open this file

```
ClientPolicy.ini
```

and on the line

```
FilenameExclusionList = |~|.bin|.cache|node_modules|
```

Put the filename or folders names that you want to skip sync

Comment: That didn't work for me. The folder `node_modules` and its contents did get synced. And yes I closed and reopened OneDrive for Business.

Comment: On MacOS the path is (very hard to find): `/System/Volumes/Data/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/OneDrive`. The folder is not visible using finder, you must `cd` to it in terminal then "open ."